# Not getting mugged!

Tags: recording, safety

Hi folks,

How cautious do you find yourself having to be when recording in the city? I'd love to be out recording more with by mics and pres, but am just so concerned about getting gear grabbed while I'm engrossed in the recording!

Anyone here ever been mugged while recording?

Another thought is that recording gear generally doesn't 'look' expensive once it's in a battered portabrace and a mic in a furry just looks unappealing - so do we think thieves might not be aware of the value?

Answer (score 4):

I did a lot of night shooting in Downtown Los Angeles for a photo project a while back.  I was concerned someone might jump me for my camera gear, so I brought someone along to watch my back as I shot.  If you are concerned about your safety, bring a friend along.

Comment: if i may add, bring a friend who knows how to be silent :) not the scuffling/coughing type ;)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, where do you live? I live in Amsterdam, which is not considered a very violent city.
Getting mugged here is not a normal thing to happen in most neirbourhoods.
I have recorded here, in china, tunesia, greece and several other european countries without any fear.

Getting mugged is not a thing i'm worried about, simply because i tend to isolate myself from a scene. 
Or I have a stealth setup and nobody notices the gear. But I don't go into neighbourhoods where i wouldn't
feel safe, with or without gear.

The only situation i fear is having my gear stolen on trains, but i always keep them close.

Arnoud

Comment: Good to hear that you've recorded in such a variety of places without any hassle! I'm in Dublin, which I've found to be generally quite safe; of course, as you say, that safety always depends on being aware of your surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you're probably too prominent a target whenever a boom is involved. Don't forget, that however much attention you are attracting from thieves, you are also doing so from the general public, and that is probably more of a deterrent. At least it is in my head. I'm usually more worried about someone calling the cops and making it a hassle for me to explain what I'm doing.

As a general rule though, I wouldn't even go about recording in a space if I felt that my personal safety was being threatened. It would probably mess me up too much just thinking about it and I'll be too worried to concentrate on the recording.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, and I find recording to be such a focussed task any distractions take away from the experience. Good point about hassle from the general public. I've had it once or twice with security guards. Do you have a stealth set up?

Answer (score 1):

Bring a small portable recorder with you, like a tascam DR07, and pretend it's a taser if someone starts giving you shit!

Comment: This could go badly wrong.